# How to use the redirect_field_name in Django's auhviews?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django project involving multiple types of users. For that, I have not created new User classes, rather I have just extended the model using a OneToOne relation (like we do while creating a profile model). Model in one app is like this:

```
class Dev(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    BaseSkills = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectBaseSkills,
        help_text='Adding Base skills help us to identify the best projects for you', blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.BigIntegerField(
        help_text="Don't add the country code (the user base is restricted to India for now)")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

and in the other app is like this:

```
class Hirer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Hirer')
    PhoneNumber = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
```

This shows how there are two types of users: Devs and Hirers.
Now since there are multiple user types, I need to redirect the different users to different urls after login, so I can't just rely on the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL settings. Also I don't want to define a login view myself, so I am using the default LoginView from django auth.
Here is the urls.py for the app where Dev user is used:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='dev_user/login.html'), name='dev-login'),
    path('register/', views.Register, name='dev-register')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And the one where Hirer user is used:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='client_user/login.html'), name='client-login'),
    path('register/', views.Register, name='client-register'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) it is said that we can override the redirect url by using the redirect_field_name in GET field of the LoginView. But there's not example code or something, and I'm quite new at programming, so I don't know how to do that. There are also no examples on the net, so please someone help me out here.

Comment: It means the url should look like this: `localhost:8000/login/?redirect=/admin`

Comment: Pardon my naiveness, but can you specify it in a snippet that should be changed in my project?

Comment: OK, let's say you are in an unauthorised view, but do know the email.
So you'd like to do the login and afterwards redirect to let's say /youraction
so your view must do like:
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth_login') + '?next=/youraction)

Comment: I am understanding that I'll have to write this statement. But I still don't know where I have to write them? Like somewhere in the urls.py modules or in the views module...

Comment: @ruddra is this how you meant to use it:   path('login/', auth_views.LoginView(template_name='dev_user/login.html', redirect_field_name=HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('auth_login') + '?next=/youraction')), name='dev-login'),

Comment: Using this has caused it to throw a circular import exception.

Answer (score 1):

I am grateful to all the people who answered. Though my original query was not solved, I did find a get around to do a login. Here's what I did for others to implement if they're stuck in a similar situation:
(views.py):

```
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dev-profile')

    return render(request, 'client_user/login.html')
```

(template):

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="separator-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="add-padding">
            <form method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <legend><h2 class="signup-info-title">Welcome Back Hirer!</h2></legend>
                    <div id="div_id_username" class="form-group"> 
                        <label for="username" class=" requiredField">
                            Username
                            <span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
                        </label> 
                        <div class=""> 
                            <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div_id_password" class="form-group"> 
                        <label for="password" class=" requiredField">
                            Password
                            <span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
                        </label> 
                        <div class=""> 
                            <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="password"> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <button class="login-buttons" type="submit">Login</button>
                <hr>
                <div class="login-footers">
                    <p class="text-muted">Don't have an account? <a href="">Sign up</a> as a Hirer!</p>
                    <p class="text-muted">Not a Hirer? <a href="">Login</a> or <a href="">Sign Up</a> as a Dev</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Also if you have an answer to the original query, please do answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (in your views):

```
@login_required
def custom_redirect(request):
   if request.user.dev.filter(BaseSkills='xxx'):
       return redirect('xxx')
   elif request.user.dev.filter(BaseSkills='xxx'):
       return redirect('xxx')
```

Also note that best practise is to have model field names in lowercase, using underscores instead of camelCase.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer. I am grateful for that gesture. But it seems you have misunderstood some of the part maybe because my question's incomplete. I'll add some other snippets so that it is clear.

Comment: Though your answer does seem to answer my queries, I am still unclear where I should use this snippet example (i,e in the views of both apps or somewhere else).

Comment: In your views. I didn't know what different user types you meant, it wasn't clear in your question. So are the different users `Dev` and `Hirer`?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry for the incomplete question. I have added new snippets so that it can be more clear. Also, comment whatever else that might be hard to understand so that I can improve the question (as I am just beginning, my coding conventions may be very hard to understand).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could change the redirect_field_name:

```
return login_required(view_func, redirect_field_name="return_to")(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

Full Sample code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def login_exempt(view):
    view.login_exempt = True
    return view


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, 'login_exempt', False):
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return

        return login_required(view_func, redirect_field_name="return_to")(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```